# using visual studio command to copy files into outdir

Tags: command-line, copy, vcproj

In my project under "Resource Files" I have some properties files that I'd like to be copied to the output directory.  The idea is that I could just give my output directory to someone else and they'd automatically read the properties files within the bin/output directory.

I believe the way I'd go about doing this is to add a build event command line command and use the XCOPY or COPY commannds.  After having looked through the help for XCOPY the command is just

> XCOPY src dest

And I used the command: `XCOPY $(InputDir)/properties.conf $(OutDir)/properties.conf`

but it says it cannot find the file.  So I tried to find out what $(InputDir) points to, since other people got it to work, but the 'set' command in the VS command line tool only shows system env. variables and not ones available to vcprojects.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?  Maybe there's a different way to do it?

SOLN: Just used "COPY properties.conf $(OutDir)\properties.conf"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just used "COPY properties.conf $(OutDir)\properties.conf"